# Distribute R visualization to other users

Tags: r, web, rendering, visualization, networkd3

How can I distribute R visualizations to other users that don't have R?

I have a created a Sankey diagram in R based on the following code ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571899/sankey-diagram-in-r)), which works great:

```
library(networkD3)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)
energy <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json" %>% 
  fromJSON
sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, 
          Nodes = energy$nodes, 
          Source = "source",
          Target = "target", 
          Value = "value", 
          NodeID = "name",
          units = "TWh", 
          fontSize = 12, 
          nodeWidth = 30)
```

But, how can I pass this diagram to other users? I was thinking maybe to render it in a web page, but I don't know how.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How about good old images? If you want to also include some text, you can try `rmarkdown` and `knitr`.

Comment: The images are missing the interaction available in the chart. If you run the code you will see that when you hover in the chart in R you get a tool-tip and the link between nodes get highlighted. You miss that with just an image.

Comment: What's about [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/)?

Comment: I can not figure out how to use shiny to add this type of diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RStudio then you can compile an HTML report using GUI:
[image]
This will quickly create an HTML file with your code and the interactive plot.

Alternatively, you could also knit an R markdown document with your code. More info [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/). Please bear in mind that only HTML version will be interactive.

Comment: The button you mention doesn't really compile the HTML. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried: rmarkdown::render('C:/path/r_sankeyDiagram.R') but I'm getting an error message: there is no package called 'jsonlite'

Comment: this means that you don't have the jsonlite package installed. just run `install.packages("jsonlite")` before compiling the report.